# Performing calculation as value changes in a textbox reseting my RangeValidated message

Tags: c#, asp.net, autopostback, rangevalidator

I am performing a calculation after user enters input into fields. Each field is range validated. Each field has `AutoPostBack` is set to true.

When user enter input into first field, then click on second field; the first field gets validated, but then auto post back kicks in and the validation looses it's value after page briefly reloads.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: You can disable autoPostback and try to use ajax instead.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?  Are the calculations sensitive, are they cumulative (e.g. are you running calculations in each field as you go through then?) Do you need to post back at all?  Can you not use JQuery validation instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Set `CausesValidation="true"` in your `TextBox`

Comment: This seems to answer my question!!! But I also got another question :) Is there a way to perform the same validation for 8 other fields? If it's too complicated, then say so :P

Comment: Only if I could at this time :P